# Why the Y axis scale is invisible and doesn't match with the actual value when using python matplotlib to draw graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
#-*-coding:utf-8 -*-

import csv
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Time=[]
Temperature=[]

plt.figure()

with open('Temperature.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header_row = next(plots)
    for column in plots:
        Time.append(time.strftime(column[0]))
        Temperature.append(column[1])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 100, 20))

plt.plot(Time, Temperature, linewidth=5)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlwyM.jpg)

As title, the Y scale isn't visible and the graph value which is 28 actually is set as zero on the axis. So there is some issue for code?

Comment: Probably the root of your problem is that your `Temperature` list is not numeric, I think it's probably `str`. Try `type(Temperature[0])` to make sure

Comment: In order to create a plot with propper units your data needs to be numeric or (in case of dates) be of type `datetime`.

Comment: It is a csv file, and I can open it as txt format. The specific data is as follows. I grab the Time column and Temperature culumn(numeric?)  to draw graph.                                                            
                                                                                  
Time,Temperature
17:42:59,28.000
17:43:02,28.000
17:43:06,28.000
17:43:09,28.000
17:43:13,28.000
17:43:16,28.000
17:43:20,28.000
17:43:24,28.000
17:43:27,28.000
17:43:31,28.000

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. I modify the Temperature.append(column[1]) as Temperature.append(float(column[1])), then it seems ok! Thank you so much for your answer!